# is it possible to remote access to mysql database on shared hostings?

Tags: mysql, database

I have a website on a shared hosting that uses a MySQL database, Is it possible to directly access and query to this database in client applications without using a webservice?

Using DBVisualizer to connect to the database using its IP, I am getting timeout for initializing the connection. The IP responds to the ping but it does not allow to access the database on the host.

I know that there are some configurations to allow remote access to the database while you set up a sever, but I don't know if it is possible to do it on shared hosting with CPanel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most default installations, MySQL binds to 127.0.0.1 - which only allows local connections.

If you wish to change that (ATTENTION: it might be a security issue), you need to change it in the configuration file (usually `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` in linux distributions).
Or in windows it might be on these locations:

```
C:\Windows\my.ini C:\Windows\my.cnf C:\my.ini C:\my.cnf 
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.ini 
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\my.cnf
```

Usually it's enough to comment out the `bind-address` line like this, which will allow connections from all IPs:

```
# bind-address          = 127.0.0.1
```

It is also worth noting that most webhosters won't allow MySQL connections from arbitrary hosts and you can't change that fact (you may only access your MySQL instance by using a local application - in most cases phpmyadmin).

Comment: Tnx a lot , i contacted my hosting support and they told me that they don't support external MySQL connection , now i'm thinking about VPS ( but i don't have the money ) or trying to implement that by writing some web services that execute SQL Queries and return some data from data base , it really takes time and energy but i don't know any easier solution

Comment: What do you need a MySQL DB for anyways? A barebones MySQL instance is usually not really useful without an application behind it. You can always install one locally. On the other hand, there are MySQL service providers which do exactly what you want. E.g. http://www.cleardb.com/ (free for 5 MB if you want to play around)

Answer (score 0):

Not a simple answer. Most likely either Firewall or Port Forwarding related.
Depending on where MySQL is installed - in a shared environment, a cloud environment, a home environment, a data center environment, etc. with different kinds of equipment protecting that network, you will need to change many settings.

These are the 2 common most places to check:

1. Check the settings of your Firewall on your local computer - make sure port 3306 TCP is open.
2. Check the settings of the firewall located on the node that is assigned the public IP (for instance your **home router** if your MySQL is run from home). You will usually need to Forward a Port tot your local computer. This could be anything from a router to an actual hardware firewall.

My answer is general as I do not know your network configuration - but doing this should allow you to connect to your MySQL server from outside.

Finally; I do not recommend that you open your database port to the world. It can be considered a security risk.
MySQL being a pretty secure package, it can be done, but at your own risk.

Comment: i don't think if its about my computer's firewall